# Filling polygons with color

Tags: graphics, color, tutorials

Is there any good tutorial/approach in LaTeX for drawing polygons filled with color?

**EDIT**: I would like to use **pdfLaTeX** interpreter

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can use `TikZ` for instance. There is a node shape `regular polygon`, it can be used like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a in {3,...,8}{
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\a, minimum size=2cm, anchor=south, fill=blue!40] at (\a*4,0) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the following result:

[image: Regular polygons in TikZ]

Note that you can determine the color by changing `fill=blue!40` to any color definition you like. If you want to add a border to the polygon, you can use the `draw` option on the node. You can change the color of that by using `draw=color`. You don't *need* to use a node, you can of course contruct a regular polygon path, but a node is the easiest way to directly get a regular polygon.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention - I would like to use pdfLaTeX interpreter. Now I see *! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found.* for you example.

Comment: I have found solution by myself. I use **\documentclass{article}** instead of **\documentclass{standalone}** and it works!

Comment: That just means you don't have the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class. You can just as easily use `article` as the documentclass. I just used `standalone` in order to get a nice `pdf` to upload as an example.